# Jekyll and Github Pages: local site is good, gh keeps initial version

Tags: git, jekyll, github-pages

So I'm slowly making my way building a Jekyll website and blog on gh-pages. 
I'm pretty confident that my set up is correct. The website generates beautifully locally and it was going fine on gh-pages as well. Today though, I added my post list and a few minor changes. However none of those changes are reflected on my gh-page.

My site is: http://bitcolorine.github.io/Je-suis-eclectique/

My repository is here: https://github.com/bitcolorine/Je-suis-eclectique

I have added and committed everything. I'm pretty sure it's a folder or baseurl problem but I don't know where to look or how to fix it.

If anyone could help me take a look it would be fantastic. I'm a bit cross-eyed by now.

Answer (score 1):

You css is 404 :-(
The base URL seems to be ok. So just commit and push your css and everything will be ok.